# How to highlight all inside-a-line word duplicates?

Tags: regex, vim

I have this plain text file :

```
1 : Foo Bar Bar Baz
2 : The dog The cat the hamster
3 : the dog the cat the hamster
4 : The dog the cat the hamster The Doors
```

and I want to highlight all the repeated words.

I have tinkered this solution :

```
/\(\<\w\+\>\)\zs[ w]\+\1
```

This works well with the first line (the second Bar is highlighted) but this does not solve the following problems :

line 2 : it highlights the second "The", but not the lowercase "the"

line 3 : it highlights only the first repetition of "the"

line 4 : it highlights only the second "The" (the first repeated word), but not the second "the" (the other repeated word)

PS : just for the sake of it, a side question : is it possible to highlight repeated words in neighbouring lines so as to see the repetition of the same word on a span of 3 lines ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works slightly better:

```
/\(\<\w\+\>\).\{-}\zs\<\1\>
```

Changes:

- Replaced `[ w]\+` by `.\{-}` (match *any* character between the pair of words; non-greedy quantifier).
- Moved `\zs` forward.
- Surrounded `\1` by `\<...\>`; these anchors are *not* automatically inherited from the capturing subpattern.

---

Unfortunately, there is one remaining problem; the third "the" on line 3 and the second "the" on line 4 are not matched due to overlap with another match. This can be resolved by using a look-behind pattern `\@<=` (with a possible performance penalty) instead of `\zs`:

```
/\%(\<\1\>.\+\)\@<=\(\<\w\+\>\)
```

Getting this to work was a bit of trial and error; it requires:

- **not** to use capturing subpatterns in the look-behind pattern (i.e. use `\%(...\)` instead of `\(...\)`)
- **not** to use non-greedy quantifiers in the look-behind pattern (i.e. go back to OP's `\+` instead of `{-}`)

The following optional additions can be used in both patterns:

- Add `\c` to the pattern for case-insensitivity.
- Replace `.` by `\_.` to find word duplicates across line breaks.

Please note with the second pattern, a cross-line match has limited scope. Look-behind searches backward no further than one line. This is by design, to avoid serious performance issues. So duplicate words are recognized as such only when the two words are on the same line, or on lines immediately following each other.

---

Things become easier if we follow Qeole's example to match the first word(s), rather than the last one(s); we can use a look-ahead, which does not have most of the drawbacks involved with look-behind. Here it is, complete with case-insensitivity and cross-line matching:

```
/\<\(\w\+\)\>\(\_.\+\<\1\>\)\@=\c
```

We can even combine the two pattern with `\|` to include *both* the first and the last word in the search results:

```
/\%(\<\1\>\_.\+\)\@<=\(\<\w\+\>\)\|\<\(\w\+\)\>\(\_.\+\<\1\>\)\@=\c
```

---

Important note from Peter Rincker: lookbehind may not work in some versions of VIM 7.4 due to a bug in the NFA regex engine. You can force it to use the old backtracking engine and get the desired results by prepending the pattern `\%#=1`. See `:h NFA` for more information. Do not use in VIM 7.3 and older.

```
/\%#=1\%(\<\1\>\_.\+\)\@<=\(\<\w\+\>\)\|\<\(\w\+\)\>\(\_.\+\<\1\>\)\@=\c
```

Comment: Or `/\(\<\w\+\>\)\ze.\{-}\<\1\>` could be used to hilight all occurences of repeted words, except for the last one. Couldn't make `\@<=` work for me, seems that `\1` is empty. @ThG: And don't forget to `:set ignorecase` to fix case problems (`The` vs. `the`).

Comment: @Qeole: Or `\c` as an alternative for `:set ignorecase`; thanks for the suggestion anyway, I edited my answer.

Comment: @Ruud : Your first answer works as you say (with the limit you signaled) ; I could not make your second solution work. Thanks nevertheless, this was helpful.

Comment: @Qeole : Your answer highlights the repeated word, not the repetition, which, really, is not a big problem. Thank you very much (sorry I cannot credit you with a "useful answer"...

Comment: @ThG: please see my edit; the last pattern does the trick as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Ruud : I still cannot make it work... Sorry, and thanks again

Comment: @Ruud :  As for the repetition across line breaks, it works, but only on the second occurrence (e.g. the second "cat"), but not on the third (line 4). My question seems to be trickier than I had imagined ; anyhow your answers will help me a lot.

Comment: It should be noted that your lookbehind may not work in some versions of vim 7.4 due to a bug in the NFA regex engine. You can force it to use the old backtracking engine and get the desired results: `/\%#=1\%(\<\1\>.\+\)\@<=\(\<\w\+\>\)`. See `:h NFA` for more information

Comment: Thanks Peter, I wasn't aware of that. My Ubuntu 12.04 machine comes with VIM 7.3; works fine there. @ThG: `/\%(\<\1\>\_.\+\)\@<=\(\<\w\+\>\)` even finds "cat" both on line 3 and 4; wondering what's your VIM version?

Comment: I am using vim 7.4 patches 1-52

Comment: @PeterRincker : your solution works perfectly and highlights the repetition (second occurrence). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Ruud : I am using Vim 7.4 patches 1-258 (Mac OS X Terminal via MacPorts)

Comment: @ThG: I added a pattern that finds both the repeated word _and_ the repetition. By the way, VIM 7.3 does not understand Peter's `\%#=1` fix; the search will find nothing. So the different VIM versions need slightly different patterns.

Comment: @Ruud (and Peter Rincker) : solution(s) accepted. Thank you very much

Comment: @PeterRincker: I took the liberty of adding your note to my answer, as it played a vital role in OP's acceptance.

Comment: @PeterRincker: Thanks for info and fix about that bug on Vim 7.4! That explains why lookbehind wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This is an approximate answer, gathering what I wrote in comments for @Ruud's answer and OP's question.

First, here is a quick workaround to fix case problems (`The` vs. `the`):

```
:set ignorecase
```

Ruud's proposal to use `\c` is probably better, though.

Then here is a proposal to hilight occurrences of repeated word, **including first appearance** of word on line, but **excluding the last one**:

```
/\(\<\w\+\>\)\ze.\{-}\1
```

It's pretty similar to Ruud's solution (even if I got it on my own). If anyone has a fix for the last occurrence on line, I'm interested in learning it.

---

As Ruud − again − also pointed out, one solution might be to use Vim `\@<=`. There's an interesting example in documentation for this `\@<=` regex atom:

```
/\1\@<=,\([a-z]\+\)
```

should match `,abc` in `abc,abc`, but I couldn't make this example work (seems to me that `\1` remains empty).

And I have no idea for side question, sorry.